# How do I pan in Figma presentation mode?

Tags: figma

In Figma presentation mode, with 100% zoom one can't see the whole screen, but I can't also find out how to pan.

I'm on Mac, how do I pan to see the rest of the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press spacebar and drag the visible area. for some reason the cursor does not change to the standard "hand" icon but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the layout resolution settings in the options, as shown in the screenshot.

If for some reason you can't see it, you may have collapsed the Figma UI section.

**Press Command ⌘\ or Esc**

[image]